# Object's Children tuple index failed

Tags: scripting

In blender python console it work

```
>>> name
'table_TV'

>>> D.objects[name].children[0]
bpy.data.objects['table_TV_viewRec']
```

but if I packaged it into a function:

```
def a(group):
    for obj in group.all_objects:
        name = obj.name
        if Viewable(obj):
            bpy.data.objects[name].children[0] # error
            
            for obj_other in group.all_objects:
                if not obj_other.name == obj.name:
                    print(obj_other.name)
                    
group = bpy.data.collections['group_TV']
a(group)
```

It won't work and show me `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Function Viewable:

```
def Viewable(object):
    """
    Description:
    Check if object is visible object.

    Return: True or False
    """
    
    object_front_name = object.name.split("_")[0]
    object_last_name = object.name.split("_")[1]
    
    if object_last_name == 'TV' or object_front_name == 'cupboard':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Did you make sure that all objects in the collection have a child?

Comment: If viewable is True it must have.@XY

Comment: I don't thing so.

Comment: Viewable use the name to determine whether an object is visible or not, Return True or False.@XY

Comment: Try to test a no children object, it can return True, but no children.

Comment: I've tested it, same error occured in line `bpy.data.objects[name].children[0]`.

Comment: Obviously, whether the function returns True has nothing to do with whether the object has child objects. So, it out of index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137684/discussion-between-winertoz-botawar-and-x-y).